# calculating diffrent of the time in datetime field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

i have a datetime field in my table and want to calculate only different of it time and not it date with mysql functions
like this:

```
datetime1 : 2013-04-08 08:30:00
datetime2 : 2013-03-08 08:35:00
```

and another sample :

```
datetime1 : 2013-04-08 08:30:00
datetime2 : 2013-04-08 08:20:00
```

and different of this 2 field's time is just 5 min and -10 min.
i want to calculate all of this different and get a average of this time's in the table.

many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, one can use MySQL's [`TIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function to extract only the time part of a `DATETIME` value:

```sql
SELECT TIME(datetime1), TIME(datetime2)
```

One could furthermore combine this with [`TIMEDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) to obtain the difference between two such times:

```sql
SELECT TIMEDIFF(TIME(datetime2), TIME(datetime1))
```

However, since the result is expressed as a `TIME` datatype, and none of the aggregation functions will work with such a datatype, obtaining the average is somewhat more difficult.  Instead, I recommend the following hackery:

```sql
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(
         UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SUBTIME(datetime2, TIME(datetime1)))
       - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(datetime2))
       ))
FROM   my_table
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to calculate the average, I recommend you use UNIX timestamps, as there are no negative values for `DATETIME`, which renders a normal average useless.

```
SELECT
  AVG(
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime2)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime2)
  ) AS average
FROM tablename
```

will give you the average in seconds.

If you want it in pseudo-`DATETIME` format, use

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    IF(average<0,"-",""),
    FROM_UNIXTIME(ABS(average))
  ) AS averagedt
FROM (
    -- above query here
)
```